# Sharepoint - Workflow Email Checkin Comment

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, checkin

I'm very new to SharePoint.  --I need to send an email on document checkin that contains the checkin comment, modified by, and document link.  Can someone please give some direction on how to do this?  (We are on version 2013 on prim but moving to Microsoft hosted in a couple of months.)

Using SP Designer, I was able to create a workflow on document change but that's not checkin.  Not sure how to trigger on checkin or how to find the checkin information.  If all possible, I would like to not have to write any custom code. Any examples would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

You say 'document change is not check-in', but that statement is incorrect: **Check-in** IS the same as document change for libraries where check-in is enabled.

In fact, if check-in is required, then a document-change workflow will not run unless and until the document is checked in.

To get your desired result, you'll need to specify the fields in a SPDesigner workflow. The Check in Comment is an available field, as well as Modified, and Modified By, and Encoded Absolute URL, (which you can put in the middle of an A anchor tag in the body of the email or just leave it as is).

I'm presently working on just such a thing, and will furnish more details soon.

Answer (score 0):

As you alluded to, this can be completed using SPD.

You could use SharePoint Designer (SPD) to Create a Workflow that could copy the Check In Comments into another field whenever a document is created or updated.

You would need to create a new field in the document library eg. "All Check In Comments"

Then go to SPD create a new List workflow for the document library.

Create a workflow variable (Set Workflow Variable) to store the current value from "Check In Comments"

Then set the "All Check In Comments" field (Set Field in Current Item) with the value of the variable you created.

To prevent the field from being overwritten you will want to click the ... button in value section to open the String Builder.

Then you'll need to add lookup for "All Check In Comments" and the workflow variable with the current Check in Comments.

[Source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176887/version-comments-in-workflow-comments)